# cannot locate symbol "EVP_cast5_cbc" on Android

Tags: android, openssl, dlopen, libssh2, libcrypto

I recently built **libssh2** for Android using **OpenSSL** as a crypto backend, I also built libcrypto.so and libssl.so myself using the NDK.
In my build process I generate a final libcustom.so linked with libssh2.a.

Google said "If you tried to use your own copy of OpenSSL but forgot to bundle it with your app's APK, the app may run normally on versions of Android platform that includes libcrypto.so. However, the app could crash on later versions of Android that do not include this library (such as, Android 6.0 and later)." that's why I package libcrypto.so, libssl.so and libcustom.so into my APK.

When running an Android app that loads the libcustom.so, my app crashes with the following error: 
*failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "EVP_cast5_cbc" referenced by "libcustom.so"...* **ONLY ON ANDROID 5**.
It works well on Android 6 and above.

The symbol **EVP_cast5_cbc** is undefined but referenced in libssh2.a, but well defined in libcrypto.so.

I don't understand why it runs correctly on Android 6 and above and not on Android 5.

I thought that on Android 5, the libcrypto.so used was not the one I embed in the APK but the one from /system/lib ; so I tried to rename the libcrypto.so and build libssh2.a using the libcrypto renamed, but I am facing the same issue.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed the use of private libraries for Marshmallow and above; this may be the case that you are experiencing.

Starting in Android 6.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries, which may cause your app to crash.

According to this table: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk.  You should be able to see logcat warnings when you are running Lollipop with private libraries.  For example:

```
03-21 17:07:51.502 31234 31234 W linker  : library "libandroid_runtime.so"
("/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so") needed or dlopened by
"/data/app/com.popular-app.android-2/lib/arm/libapplib.so" is not accessible
for the namespace "classloader-namespace" - the access is temporarily granted
as a workaround for http://b/26394120
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As Google said: "If you tried to use your own copy of OpenSSL but forgot to bundle it with your app's APK, the app may run normally on versions of Android platform that includes libcrypto.so. However, the app could crash on later versions of Android that do not include this library (such as, Android 6.0 and later)." that's why I bundle my version of openssl into my APK. When I run with logcat, there is no warning about a system lib I should not use. It seems that everything is fine on this side.

Comment: Ok guys I found the problem... Using readelf on my libcrypto_custom.so I found that it was still linked to libcrypto.so, so my guess was right, it was still using the libcrypto.so from the system.
What I did is patched the android.conf file on the openssl build system to add a variant:

 "mycustom-android-arm" => {
        inherit_from     => [ "android-arm"],
        shlib_variant => ".custom",
    },
Now the lib is well generated and do not used the one in the system !

Thank you